# How to display product every 4 cols of materialize?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, materialize

I have product that I want to display in every four cols of materialize. How can I achieve that task using ng-repeat?

Content of **main.html**:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="card blue-grey darken-1" ng-repeat="laptop in data">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
              <span class="card-title">{{laptop.name}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
              <a href="#">{{laptop.Brand}}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: ng-repeat is to repeat code snippet, could be rows or columns.

Do you a screen shot or what you want to achieve, so that the template can be adjusted?

Comment: product is display one item in one  row , i want to display 3 products in one row using ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the ng-repeat on the `col` instead of the `row`..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4" ng-repeat="laptop in data">
      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title">{{laptop.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="#">{{laptop.Brand}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Example: http://www.codeply.com/go/3rRmpU0NC3